# Office.context.document.settings.set Not working on Excel Mac

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am working on a excel add-in, to save some settings in to Excel.
But its not working on Excel on Mac.   Is there any other way to save settings in Excel ?

```
Office.context.document.settings.set('keyToken', values.apiKey);
        Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function(asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
               console.log("save token failed");
            } else {
                 ReactDOM.render(
                     <Home />,
                        document.getElementById("container")
                 );
           }
});
```

Excel version.

[image]

Comment: would you please share us what's the error message you are observing?

Answer (score 1):

Just verified on my Mac which is exactly the same version 16.45. I did some modifications to your code, it works on my side. I guess there are some other errors that may not related to settings. please try on the following code.

```
async function save1(){
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {

  Office.context.document.settings.set('keyToken', 'myvalue');
  Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      console.log("save token failed");
    } else {
      console.log("save token success");
    }
  });
  });
}

async function read() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync((result: Office.AsyncResult<Office.Settings>) => {
      const value1 = result.value.get("keyToken");
      console.log("current value: " + value1);
    });
  });
}
```

My Mac version:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't use 
await Excel.run(async (context)

in to the save function.

Is this the reason ? I didn't use get this issue on Windows or web